# Install shield installscript project and halting install

Tags: installation, installshield, installscript

I have struggled with InstallShield, however with a lot of trial and error and googling I have managed to create a project using installscript. The first thing it does after the welcome is call a .net assembly and deal with the return of the method. Now what I cannot seem to understand is how to deal with the return.

For example, if the dll call returns false, I want to show a message to the user advising "xyz" and for it to then show the finish dialog for not having installed anything. Now this is easy done to a degree as I can easily do

```
MessageBox("Some message here...", INFORMATION);
abort;
```

However this does exactly what the code suggests - abort. It just exits, and I assume would not do any roll back of anything that has been installed already.

Now in this instance that would be fine as it is that early in the process that nothing has been installed. However, I will be doing some similar calls later in the install process and will need to handle it properly.

How would I handle an abort properly with installscript in installshield?

Answer (score 0):

During run the install progress bar(copy files), If your project is InstallShield project, it's hard to find a way to  execute the roll back operation, but if your project is MSI project, once a function is called unsuccessful, it's can auto execute the roll back operation.

Comment: Well this is not an MSI project, it is just an installscript project